# Resolvconf is ignoring domain-names received by dhcpclient

Tags: 12.04, dhcp, resolvconf

My workstation is connected to a network which uses dhcp for IP-configuration. I'm running 12.04 which is using `/etc/network/interfaces` for the network configuration. For `eth0` I have:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Almost everything works fine. The only problem is that `resolvconf` is not taking into consideration the default domain provided by the dhcp-server when generating `resolv.conf`.

I can see in the lease-file (`/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases`) that the `option domain-name "<my correct domain-names>";` is correctly received and when monitoring `/etc/resolv.conf` while doing a `service networking restart` I can for some moments see a correct `resolv.conf`.

I assume this is between dhclient has received the information and resolvconf is invoked.

What's going wrong? Is there is configurations switch I need to toggle?

Comment: First check that `/etc/resolv.conf` is a symbolic link to `../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`. If it isn't, run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf`.

That `resolv.conf` is momentarily correct indicates that some program other than resolvconf may be overwriting the file. Do you have any third-party networking software installed, e.g., a VPN client?

Comment: Yes, it is a link. No, no VPN client. I actually thought that dhclient is the one who overwriter temporarily the resolv.conf.

Comment: Normally dhclient sends its nameserver information directly to resolvconf and does not write resolv.conf itself. In a normally configured Ubuntu 12.04 or later system nothing writes resolv.conf except resolvconf.